# Sum of independent non-normal random variables

Tags: probability

I have a very simple question:

Can a sum of independent non-normal random variables be normal? (not approximately normal, or converging in distribution to a normal after some standardization)

I have been thinking about it and I couldn't find an example or a proof that rules out this possibility. This is not a homework problem -- it's just out of curiosity.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about independent random variables. Sorry.

Comment: I've edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Where is the original question?
There is one speaking about joint normallity, not the same.